# Saving incomplete/too large visual studio solutions on github

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I have a very large c++ project written in visual studio. I am trying to upload it to github however I consistently get an error that I have files above 100mb in size which means they are not up loadable. I have briefly tried git LFS which i gave up on very quickly and than gave up on it for a while. Now i really need to save the project on github for collaborative work. The problem is not the source files but the "*.pch","*.pdb" and other build files. My question is whether i can save partial solution, maybe just .sln and source files, and still run the project properly.

While using git LFS i have received an error saying that i ran out of storage/bandwidth which is the main reason i gave up on that approach.

If you have any idea how to properly execute any of the 2 approaches i tried it will be highly apricated.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: "I have briefly tried git LFS which i gave up on very quickly" - well... don't give up?

Comment: if those files are product of the build (I have no idea), then they should not be part of version control.... and then you should _rewrite history_ to get rid of them (which would then allow you to push into github). https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Comment: @Gimby i explained later why i gave up on it.

Comment: If Windows source code can go to Git, https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/05/microsoft-windows-git/ you can hardly say no to yourself. And I don't think you dig enough into "files above 100mb in size" yet.